# Jquery modal dialog not fire in image button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net content pages along with Jquery. I am new to Jquery and using datepicker and modal dialog. Datepicker is working properly but modal dialog not working if i removed the line `autoOpen:false` from code snippet i shared below. i need modal dialog to fire when i click image button.

Please help me with this, following is my jquery code.

```
$(function () {
   var dialogshow = true;
   if (dialogshow) {
     $('#dialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 600,
      closeOnEscape: true,
      resizable: false,
      draggable: true,
      modal: true,
      title: 'Add New Project',
       show: {
        effect: 'blind',
        duration: 1000
       },
       hide: {
        effect: 'explore',
        duration: 1000
       }
     });
    }
});

$("#ImgProjAdd").click(function () {
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  return false;
});

//my asp.net code to generate image button
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImgProjAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/plus2.png" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function OpenJqueryDialog() {
            $('#dialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false, bigframe: true, modal: true, width: 450, closeOnEscape: true, resizable: false, show: { effect: 'blind', duration: 1000 }, hide: { effect: 'explore', duration: 1000} });
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                        $("#iframe").attr('src', 'AddProject.aspx');
            return false;
        }

 <div id="dialog" title="Add New Project" style="width: 600px; height: 250px; display: none;">
            <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"
                scrolling="no" title="Add New Project"></iframe>
        </div>

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImgProjAdd" runat="server" OnClientClick="return OpenJqueryDialog();"
                                        ImageUrl="~/images/plus2.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

"asp:ImageButton" won't generate the same ID='ImgProjAdd' when the DOM is loaded. View you page source and navigte to 'ImgProjAdd', you will see that a value is prepend to it. You should write your "click" function for that generated ID.

Comment: Please follow the process...you will find a different id rather than which you have defined 'ImgProjAdd'. It will be like 'c435345hsdbfdf_ImgProjAdd'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$("#ImgProjAdd")` try to use the "Ends With" selector `$("[ID$=ImgProjAdd]")` first.

Control ids are modified by the .Net framework and usually the generated id ends with the id you used.

Second, move the definition of the click inside `$(...)` like this:

```
$(function () {
   var dialogshow = true;
   if (dialogshow) {
     $('#dialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 600,
      closeOnEscape: true,
      resizable: false,
      draggable: true,
      modal: true,
      title: 'Add New Project',
       show: {
        effect: 'blind',
        duration: 1000
       },
       hide: {
        effect: 'explore',
        duration: 1000
       }
     });
    }

    $("[ID$=ImgProjAdd]").click(function () {
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
      return false;
    });
});
```